# Create a New ChromiumWebBrowser from a POST request (as a tab)

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

On Chromium/Google Chrome if I have a POST with target="_blank" that returns a PDF it creates a new window(or tab) showing the PDF.

In my case I want to force a new tab, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. Here's what I've tried so far:

- **Hookup to LifeSpanHandler.OnBeforePopUp**. From here I can force a new Tab instead of letting it open a new windows as it pleases. But I can't seem to get the original request that triggered the PopUp, only the Url.
- **Hookup to RequestHandler.OnBeforeBrowse**. From here I can get the request. But I don't see a way to start a ChromiumWebBrowse and pass the request.

I'm using CefSharp.Wpf 39.0.0-pre03 and I basically derived from the "CefSharp.Wpf.Example" from the CefSharp GitHub repository.

Any helps or ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Do you need to pass the request or simply open the `PDF` url in a new tab?

Comment: I want the PDF that is a result from the POST(with target="_blank") to open in a new tab. I implemented a very crude solution that I am not happy with... but will share as an answer until I get something better.

Comment: `CefSharp` doesn't currently expose the ability to post data using a request. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/912 for an open issue. If this is something you require then continue the discussion there.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an "undesirable" solution for this. I'd prefer something more robust, but I'm sharing what I did in case is the only way to work around it for now.

1. Have a list of URLs that are "POST with target='_blank'" stored somewhere where your application can retrieve it. Like the app.config.
2. In the **LifeSpanHandler.OnBeforePopUp** check for the URL that is triggering the popup. Notice that this method does not provide you with the METHOD nor the parameters, meaning that this will only work if this URL is only ever used as POST to open a new window. It will have undesired behavior if the same URL is used with a GET or other METHOD.
3. In the **RequestHandler.OnBeforeBrowse** check for the URL that is a POST and matches the list of URLs. Have it call a function that creates your new tab and then injects javascript to invoke the desired POST with the parameters (you can get all this from the Request received by **OnBeforeBrowse**)

Like this I can sort of emulate the desired behavior. The problem is that any new "situation" would required adding a new URL and it must only ever trigger a new window as a POST and never used to not trigger a window as a POST.

This problem arises from using sites that have **form**s that have target='_blank' and that the desired behavior is to open the new window as a tab.